# What pony has this sun and hearts cutie mark?

Tags: object-identification, my-little-pony

Can anyone tell me what pony, if any, has this sun and hearts cutie mark? It popped up on a list of cutie marks, but I couldn’t find who it belongs to.

[image: yellow sun and three red hearts]

Comment: When you say "pony", I'm assuming you meant one of _My litlle pony_ ones?

Comment: Also, could you give us the link of that "list of cutie marks" please?

Comment: Asked a friend who's a big fan of MLP, he said he couldn't remember any pony with this mark so it must be a fan creation, not an official one.

Comment: I think @Sava is right about this mask as fan creation. Cutie Mark (Sun and Hearts) was created by Scrucee for the My Little Pony Roleplay games (Last update on Jun. 21, 2013). Link here:
https://www.roblox.com/library/119885169/Cutie-Mark-Sun-and-Hearts

Comment: @Palliser - No it wasn't; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/196160/20774. It was from a low-canon licenced property.

Answer (score 6):

These marks are from a Hasbro licenced My Little Pony game called

> *[HappyStudio](http://happystudio.com/): My Little Pony*

basically an interactive toy that came free with various McDonalds Happy Meal® promotions.

[image]

You can play the full game online [here](https://www.deviantart.com/lordprevious/art/McDonald-s-My-Little-Pony-Game-294421421)

Answer (score 1):

I've reverse-searched the image on google and appears to be a cutie mark [from a game called "Stable Salon."](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Cutie_marks/Gallery#Cutie_marks_from_the_Stable_Salon_game) I can't find any information about the game itself though, for some reason.

[image]

Comment: "Stable salon" doesn't exist. I'm not sure why the person who posted that article called it that and yet labelled the pictures correctly as being from HappyStudio.